# djangorestframework store file from POST to s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

Hy all,

I spend a lot of time googling this without real result.

I want upload file to Aws s3 (file can be large), I get the file with post request.

I have tried the code in officiel documentation of boto using filechunkIO, but it's not work on python 3.4, it's work only for python 2.7.

```
def post(self, request):
    file = request.FILES['file']


     #upload to s3
     .....


     return Response(true, 200)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [django-s3direct](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct). There's an input form class that uploads directly to s3. Simple and easy.

If you are having errors at the upload stage, post the errors. Otherwise we have no idea where you're having an issue.

Comment: it seems that django-s3direct use Javascript for upload not python. I want upload files with python (boto).